# Пустой массив из JSON swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift, парсер

Мне приходит пустой массив

> []

```
public func getLastestNews(_ url: String) {
    print("Start Download")
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:  { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        //Parsing
        if let data = data {
            self.parseJSONData(data)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

// MARK: - Parse Data
private func parseJSONData(_ data: Data) {
    do {
        let temp: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        let myNSData = temp.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myNSData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        let jsonNews = jsonResult["posts"] as! [AnyObject]
```

Как правильно парсить пустой массив?

На предпоследей строке  пишет ошибку

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x108930db0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x108931288).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариантов два:

1)

```
guard let array = jsonResult["posts"] as? [AnyObject] else {
    // действия если массив пустой
}
```

2)

```
if let array = jsonResult["posts"] as? [AnyObject] {
     // действия если массив не пустой
} else {
    // действия если массив пустой
}
```

`jsonResult["posts"] as! [AnyObject]` - Так конечно будет крэш, вся суть в `as!`, Вы пытаетесь сделать `implicitly unwrap`, когда Вы так делаете, Вы должны быть уверены, что значение не равно `nil`. Тоесть Вы должны проверить значение на `nil`, прежде чем делать `implicitly unwrap`.

Comment: Отличный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо `Vitali Eller` за ответ. Но тут я напишу правильный ответ который заработал у меня.

```
guard let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myNSData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary else {
        return
    }
guard let jsonNews = jsonResult["posts"] as? [AnyObject] else {
        return
    }
```

Comment: Все верно, ранее вы делали `force unwrap`, а так как значение было пустое был крэш. Старайтесь и далее в коде всегда избегать `!`

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам приходит пустой массив `[]`, то падает он у Вас на строке

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myNSData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

Т.к. он не может привести и сделать `force unwrap` массива в `Dictionary`, о чем и говорит:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x108930db0) to
>   'NSDictionary' (0x108931288)

Вам  необходимо либо обрабатывать возможные варианты ответа:
Если пустой - то массив, если не пустой - Dictionary? Костыли какие-то. Или же массив должен приходить? Тогда и разбирайте его как массив.

И старайтесь держаться подальше от `!`, лучше `optional binding`:

```
if let constantName = someOptional {
    statements
}
```